# dpkg: error processing package linux-image-amd64 (--configure): dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

Tags: linux-kernel, kali-linux, dpkg, dependencies

I'm using an HP laptop and am seeing these messages:

```
sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.142) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-image-5.18.0-kali5-amd64 (5.18.5-1kali6) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.18.0-kali5-amd64
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/cml_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/dg1_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/adlp_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/adlp_dmc_ver2_14.bin for module i915
raspi-firmware: missing /boot/firmware, did you forget to mount it?
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//z50-raspi-firmware exited with return code 1
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.18.0-kali5-amd64 (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.18.0-kali5-amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-amd64:
 linux-image-amd64 depends on linux-image-5.18.0-kali5-amd64 (= 5.18.5-1kali6); however:
  Package linux-image-5.18.0-kali5-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.142) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.18.0-kali5-amd64
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/cml_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/dg1_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/adlp_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/adlp_dmc_ver2_14.bin for module i915
raspi-firmware: missing /boot/firmware, did you forget to mount it?
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//z50-raspi-firmware exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.18.0-kali5-amd64
 linux-image-amd64
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you’re not using a Raspberry Pi, you don’t need the `raspi-firmware` package; that’s what’s causing the errors. Run

```
sudo rm /etc/kernel/postinst.d/z50-raspi-firmware
sudo apt purge raspi-firmware
```

You need to *purge* the package, not just remove it, to ensure that the various `z50-raspi-firmware` scripts are removed too. The postinst script needs to be removed separately because [it breaks on non-Raspberry Pi systems](https://bugs.debian.org/1040896).

Answer (score 1):

Issue command

```
sudo mv /etc/initramfs/post-update.d/z50-raspi-firmware
```

Do this will move the Z50 firmware to your home directory, preventing it from running every time you try and upgrade.

I moved it to the home directory to keep a backup just in case something broke.

Comment: I installed Debian 12 from a live cd, and that wasn't enough, because it couldn't even complete the purge. I also had to: sudo rm /etc/kernel/postinst.d/z50-raspi-firmware

Answer (score 0):

When installed debian-12 from a live CD, I had similar errors with `apt upgrade` and here's what has fixed it:

```
$ sudo dpkg -P raspi-firmware
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the blog post on : https://itsfoss.com/dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1/ a solve to the issue is to **Remove post info files of the troublesome package** causing the installation to error out as it the cases for you with the 3 packages mention in the **Errors were encountered while processing section** by doing :

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/<packge name>.* /tmp
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem as the accepted answer does. Also "remove post info files" is not what you are doing when you move them to /tmp. Sure they "might" be deleted upon reboot, but they might not.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).