# Reinstalling dpkg and apt on Debian 12

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, dpkg, reinstall

How to completely reinstall `dpkg` and its `apt` front-end?

I tried to run `sudo apt remove virtualbox` , and my output was:

```
Reading list of packages ... done
Dependencies tree generation ... done
Reading information on the state ... done
Note, "Virtualbox-7.0" is selected instead of "Virtualbox"
The following packages have been installed automatically and are no longer requested:
   Linux-Headers-6.1.0-9-Amd64 Linux-Headers-6.1.0-9-COMMON
   Linux-IMAGE-6.1.0-9-AMD64
Use "SUDO APT Autoremove" to remove them.
0 Updated, 0 installed, 0 to be removed and 0 not updated.
3 not completely installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 b of disk space will be occupied.
Configuration of IniTramfs-Tools (0.142) ...
Update-Iritramfs: Deverring Update (Trigger Activated)
Linux-IMAGE-6.1.0-11-AMD64 (6.1.38-4) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
Update-arthramfs: Generating /boot/inithrd.img-6.1.0-11-Ad64
I: The IniTramfs Will Attamp to Resume From /Dev /Nvme0n1p3
I: (UUID = 60E79831-EF20-462B-B23C-7Fe0ba626a11)
I: Set the resume variable to override this.
Raspi-Firmware: Missing /Boot /Firmware, Did You Forget To Mount it?
Run-parts:/ETC/initramfs/post-Update.d//z50-Raspi-firmware Exited with Return C
ode 1
Run-parts:/ETC/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools Exited with Return Code 1
DPKG: Error in elaborating the Linux-IMAGE-6.1.0-11-AMD64 package (--Configure
):
  The subcifuro installed Linux-IMAGE-6.1.0-11-AMD64 Post-In Script
Stallaction has returned the state of error 1
Linux-IMAGE-6.1.0-10-AMD64 (6.1.38-2) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
Update-arthramfs: Generating /boot/inithrd.img-1.0-10-Ad64
I: The IniTramfs Will Attamp to Resume From /Dev /Nvme0n1p3
I: (UUID = 60E79831-EF20-462B-B23C-7Fe0ba626a11)
I: Set the resume variable to override this.
Raspi-Firmware: Missing /Boot /Firmware, Did You Forget To Mount it?
Run-parts:/ETC/initramfs/post-Update.d//z50-Raspi-firmware Exited with Return C
ode 1
Run-parts:/ETC/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools Exited with Return Code 1
DPKG: Error in elaborating the Linux-IMAGE-6.1.0-10-AMD64 package (--Configure
):
  The subciest installed Linux-IMAGE-6.1.0-10-AMD64 Post-In script package
Stallaction has returned the state of error 1
Trigger processing for IniTramfs-Tools (0.142) ...
Update-arthramfs: Generating /boot/inithrd.img-6.1.0-11-Ad64
I: The IniTramfs Will Attamp to Resume From /Dev /Nvme0n1p3
I: (UUID = 60E79831-EF20-462B-B23C-7Fe0ba626a11)
I: Set the resume variable to override this.
Raspi-Firmware: Missing /Boot /Firmware, Did You Forget To Mount it?
Run-parts:/ETC/initramfs/post-Update.d//z50-Raspi-firmware Exited with Return C
ode 1
DPKG: Error in elaborating the IniTramfs-Tools package (-Configure):
  The Instremfs-Tools Script Post-Installation Package Installed Package
returned the state of error 1
Errors have occurred in elaboration:
  Linux-IMAGE-6.1.0-11-AMD64
  Linux-IMAGE-6.1.0-10-AMD64
  IniTramfs-Tools
E: Sub-Process/USR/BIN/DPKG Returned An Error Code (1)
```

Comment: I need to reinstall dpkg 'cause i have problems processing some packages and i can download a dpkg .deb file from some websites, right?

Comment: No, the errors you quoted above don’t mean you need to re-install `dpkg`. Please [edit] your question to include details of the command you tried to run and its full output.

Comment: dpkg is indicating that it has trouble in processing other packages, not that it has trouble with dpkg, or itself in this case.

Comment: I have a lot of space on my ssd.The same error appears with every apt or dpkg command i run.

Comment: And i know that my dpkg is not broken at all, but i think it's more defficult to try to repair it.

Comment: Anyway, i only need a way to repair or reinstall my package manager.               PS:I think this problem is caused by an update, because at the same time another debian 12 machine showed this problem.

Comment: Your problem isn’t a broken `dpkg`, it’s `raspi-firmware` — see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/711112/86440) for instructions on how to fix it.